# Why does this regex fail to work...any ideas?

Tags: php, regex

I am faced with strings as follows:

- start of line;
- characters `C`, `M`, `P`, `T`, `K`, `X`, or `Q`;
- 3 more word characters;
- any number of other characters except newline;
- space;
- possible `M` literal;
- 2 digits;
- `/`;
- possible `M` literal;
- 2 or 3 digits;
- space.

I am nearly certain I have translated this into the following regex correctly but this line of PHP code still returns NULL when passed valid strings. Furthermore, when I test this regex with regexpal and the identical subject string, the correct result is returned. I'm pretty sure I'm having a problem with the pattern delimiter or the first 2 groups (start of line then character check). Any ideas? - Brandon

```
preg_match_all('&^(\C|\M|\P|\T|\K|\X|\Q)[A-Z0-9]{3}.*\sM?[0-9]{2}/M?[0-9]{2,3}\s&', $subject, $resultArr);
```

Comment: You need delimiters `preg_match_all('/regex/', $subject, $resultArr);`.

Comment: `&` is a perfectly valid delimiter

Comment: `^` + multiple strings in match => me thinks multiline mode is desired? `/m`.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would typically suggest using a more common pattern delimiter such as `/`, `#`, or `~`. I personally would not actually use `/` here since you use that in the pattern. This is just preference though, `&` is totally valid.

Second, there is no need for backslashes along with the characters at the start of the line (you can also use a character class for these, which I find more readable). As shown, some of these do form valid escape sequences, so you are likely getting unpredictable behavior.

Third, I am guessing you want an ungreedy search (`U` pattern modifier after pattern). I find in most cases this is desired behavior when using `.*` somewhere in pattern. In this case, since you are using `preg_match_all()` a greedy search is particularly problematic, as it would match the first case where the first portion of your pattern matches along with the last case with the last part of the pattern matches with all other potential matches lumped into the `.*` portion of the pattern.

So this leaves us with something like this:

```
$pattern = '#^[CMPTKXQ][A-Z0-9]{3}.*\sM?[0-9]{2}/M?[0-9]{2,3}\s#U';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $resultArr);
```

Comment: @Wrikken Yes that is possible though he did mention that there should not be a newline.  I did not know if that meant the overall string might be multi-line, but there should not be newline within the pattern itself or whether the whole string should be a single line.

Comment: Saying there's no need for the backslashes is putting it too mildly; having them there is actually an error.  You should never place a backslash before a letter you want to match literally, because the regex will try to interpret them as escape sequences (like `\K` and `Q`, for example).